# How to Add a single feature ( features[0] ) from Geojson ( without jquery )

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, features

```
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject,{featureProjection:'EPSG:4326'});
   console.log("I_got_features[0]_as_<point>_:"+features[0].getGeometry().getType());
 console.log("features.length_as_<132>:"+features.length);
/*
var featurething = new ol.Feature({name: "point",geometry: features[0]});
*/
 var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
 //for_all_feature-----But i want Only 1 feature
 //features: features
 //so i tried all this below but failed
 //features: featurething
 //features: features[0].getGeometry()
   features: features[0]
 });
 var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
 source: vectorSource,
 });
 map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

How can i convert my features[0] as a features......

Answer (score 1):

you want to create a layer with a single feature so you must use:

```
features: [features[0]]
```